# User in administrators group cant take ownership of file or grant full access

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am writing a powershell script that creates a list of users on a newly provisioned custom Windows 2012 AMI (Amazon Machine Image).

After the script creates the users, and assigns them to a group, it restricts these users from having access to certain files and folders.

**Important -** I run the script manually by logging into the environment through RDP as a user that is assigned to the "Administrators" group.

I am getting access denied errors when trying to set another users access level.

When looking at the files "Properties -> Security" the "Administrators" group ONLY has Read/Write access, and DOESN'T own the file.

I tried using the following command:

```
takeown /f c:\windows\system32\gpedit.msc
```

And get the following error:

> ERROR: The current logged on user does not have ownership privileges on the file (or folder) "c:\windows\system32\gpedit.msc"

I then tried using this command:

```
icacls c:\windows\system32\gpedit.msc /grant "DOMAIN\UserInAdminGroup"
```

And get the following error/message:

> c:\windows\system32\gpedit.msc
>   Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

**Things Tried That Failed:**

- Running powershell in elevated mode using "Run As Administrator"
- Running command prompt in elevated mode using "Run As Administrator"

**Things Tried That Worked**

- RDPed into the machine as "Administrator"
- Used the takeown command on file
- Granted FULL access to "Administrators" group on file
- RDPed into the machine as previous user (Part of Administrators Group)
- Successfully used takeown command on file
- Successfully used icacls to restrict permissions on file for another user

**QUESTION:**
Is there something else I can try, or is the **ONLY** way to modify this files permissions to first do it using the "TRUE" Administrator account?

**EDIT-1**
Ran the "whoami /groups" command as the problem user. Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: `takeown.exe` should work fine for any user of the administrators group, even if he/she does not have any permissions to the file. The error `The current logged on user does not have ownership privileges on the file` is usually shown when the admin account is not elevated, but you said you did that, confirm in the CLI session that you are elevated, `whoami /groups` should only show `Mandatory groups`

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - Ran the command you suggested, updated original post with a screenshot of results.

Comment: The only reason I can think of for `takeown /f` to not work from an elevated window would be if the file was in use.  That doesn't seem to explain the sequence of events here, however.

Comment: One possible workaround would be to use `psexec` (available from the MS web site) and the `-s` flag to run the command in SYSTEM context.  (Although if that works, it means something *very* odd is going on.)